# How do you print multiple key values from sub keys in a .json file?

Tags: json, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

Im pulling a list of AMI ids from my AWS account and its being written into a json file.
The json looks basically like this:

```
{
"Images": [
    {
        "CreationDate": "2017-11-24T11:05:32.000Z",
        "ImageId": "ami-XXXXXXXX"
    },
            {
        "CreationDate": "2017-11-24T11:05:32.000Z",
        "ImageId": "ami-aaaaaaaa"
    },
            {
        "CreationDate": "2017-10-24T11:05:32.000Z",
        "ImageId": "ami-bbbbbbb"
    },
            {
        "CreationDate": "2017-10-24T11:05:32.000Z",
        "ImageId": "ami-cccccccc"
    },
            {
        "CreationDate": "2017-12-24T11:05:32.000Z",
        "ImageId": "ami-ddddddd"
    },
            {
        "CreationDate": "2017-12-24T11:05:32.000Z",
        "ImageId": "ami-eeeeeeee"
    }
]
```

}

My code looks like this so far after gathering the info and writing it to a .json file locally:

```
    #writes json output to file...
print('writing to response.json...')
with open('response.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(response, outfile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ': '))

#Searches file...
print('opening response.json...')
with open("response.json") as f:
    file_parsed = json.load(f)
```

The next part im stuck on is how to iterate through the file and print only the CreationDate and ImageId values.

```
print('printing CreationDate and ImageId...')
for ami in file_parsed['Images']:
    #print ami['CreationDate'] #THIS WORKS
    #print ami['ImageId']  #THIS WORKS
    #print ami['CreationDate']['ImageId']
```

The last line there gives me this no matter how I have tried it:  *TypeError: string indices must be integers*

My desired output is something like this:

```
2017-11-24T11:05:32.000Z ami-XXXXXXXX
```

Ultimately what im looking to do is then iterate through lines that are a certain date or older and deregister those AMIs. So would I be converting these to a list or a dict?
Pretty much not a programmer here so dont drown me.
TIA

Comment: You are getting this error because 'ImageId' is not the part of the 'CreationDate' object. 'CreationDate' is a string.

Comment: Right but how do you print them together on the same line? I added a desired output to my original question if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost parsed the json but for the desired output you need to concatenate the 'CreationDate' and 'ImageId' like this:

```
for ami in file_parsed['Images']:
   print(ami['CreationDate'] + " "+ ami['ImageId'])
```

Comment: Yep...that was what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`CreationDate` evaluates to a string. So you can only take *numerical* indices of a string which is why `['CreationDate']['ImageId']` leads to a TypeError. Your other two commented lines, however, were correct.

To check if the date is older, you can make use of the `datetime` module. For instance, you can take the CreationDate (which is a string), convert it to a `datetime` object, create your own based on what that certain date is, and compare the two.

Something to this effect:

```
def checkIfOlder(isoformat, targetDate):
    dateAsString = datetime.strptime(isoformat, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
    return dateAsString <= targetDate

certainDate = datetime(2017, 11, 30) # Or whichever date you want
```

So in your `for` loop:

```
for ami in file_parsed['Images']:
    creationDate = ami['CreationDate']
    if checkIfOlder(creationDate, certainDate):
        pass # write code to deregister AMIs here
```

Resources that would benefit would be [Python's datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and in particular, the [strftime/strptime directives](http://strftime.org/). HTH!